# How to get data straight from MySQL column to textbox in any order? Textbox1 = Column1, Textbox2 = Column4, Textbox3 = Column8

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

Right now I'm using "SELECT * table..." and a recordset to throw values into textbox by the number of the recordset field `textbox1 = rs.Fields(0) textbox2 = rs.Fields(1)` and so on... It works, but every time I make a change to the database its a pain in the ... to put everything back in place, is there anyway to use the column name of the database to put values in a textbox? `textbox1 = Column1 textbox2 = Column2` so adding new columns to the database would not matter since they will be selected by the column header.

I'm using this to update values from the database with a userform in excel, to do that I'm using "UPDATE table SET COLUMN1=textbox1 COLUMN2=textbox2...." Anyway I can get them the same way I'm updating so if I change the number of columns it does not get messy

What I have:

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE OS ='123'
sqlQuery = sqlQuery & ";"
rs.Source = sqlQuery
Set rs.ActiveConnection = Conn
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open


For Each field In rs.Fields
    If IsNull(rs.Fields(0)) = False Then Textbox1 = rs.Fields(0)
    If IsNull(rs.Fields(1)) = False Then Textbox2 = rs.Fields(1)
    If IsNull(rs.Fields(2)) = False Then Textbox3 = rs.Fields(2)
    If IsNull(rs.Fields(3)) = False Then Textbox4 = rs.Fields(3)
Next
```

What I need:

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE OS ='123'
sqlQuery = sqlQuery & ";"
rs.Source = sqlQuery
Set rs.ActiveConnection = Conn
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open


For Each field In rs.Fields
    If IsNull(rs.Fields(0)) = False Then Textbox1 = Column1Header
    If IsNull(rs.Fields(1)) = False Then Textbox2 = Column2Header
    If IsNull(rs.Fields(2)) = False Then Textbox3 = Column3Header
    If IsNull(rs.Fields(3)) = False Then Textbox4 = Column4Header
next
```

Comment: `rs("FieldName")` works too - you dont have to use the index value.

Comment: For real? Damn will test here!

Comment: Thank you, its working as I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rs.Fields("FieldName")` works

And since `Fields` is the default for a recordset object, `rs("FieldName")` works too

You don't have to use the index value.